# Render Partial View from JQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm a desktop developer and I'm teaching myself ASP.NET MVC3 with C# (can't use MVC4 yet...). I'm slapping together some small dummy projects for this reason. In this project I use a DropDownListFor with movie categories (we all know this example right?). But because this tutorial was going too fast I'm trying to do something more simple.

My Model:

```
public class MovieModel {

    public int SelectedCategorieID { get; set; }

    public List<CategorieModel> Categories { get; set; }

    public MovieModel() {
        this.SelectedCategorieID = 0;
        this.Categories = new List<CategorieModel>() {new CategorieModel {ID = 1,
            Name = "Drama"},
        new CategorieModel {ID = 2,
            Name = "Scifi"}};
    }
}

public class CategorieModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

See? Very simple. I have a strongly typed View in which I can use this model:

```
@model MvcDropDownList.Models.MovieModel (1st line of Index.cshtml).
```

The model is filled when the default action of the Home controller is called:

```
    public ActionResult Index() {

        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        Models.MovieModel mm = new Models.MovieModel();

        return View(mm);
    }
```

So far so good. No problems. Now I want to show the user the ID of the category it selected in a partial view with unobtrusive ajax... Because I didn't get it to work I started even smaller. Forget the DrowpdownList for now. All I have at the moment is this button:

```
<input type="button" value="Minicart test" onclick="categoryChosen();" />
```

And this div:

```
<div id="minicart">
    @Html.Partial("Information")
</div>
```

The mini cart stuff is from another tutorial, I apologize. Don't let it distract you please.

This javascript:

```
function categoryChosen() {
    var url = "Home/CategoryChosen/" + "2";
    $.post(url, function (data) {
        debugger;
        $("#miniCart").html(data);
    });
}
```

The 2 is indeed solid, from my earlier attempt to get it to work. Eventually I want that to be variable ofcourse...

Which calls this action:

```
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public ActionResult CategoryChosen(string SelectedCategorieID) {

        ViewBag.messageString = "2";

        return PartialView("Information");

    }
```

Yup, and you see that correctly. I just insert 2 for my test. Because like I said, can't get it to work. The partial view Information looks like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Information";
}

<h2>Information</h2>
<h2>You selected: @ViewBag.messageString</h2>
```

So, now for the big question. I expected the partial view to render: "You selected: 2". I even see this when I debug the javascript and look what's inside the variable 'data'. Can anyone help me why it doesn't render 2? Then I can move on with teaching myself this stuff. Thank you very much in advance for helping. If you miss any kind of information, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: I would use the integrated MVC-Ajax functionality. Take a look at Ajax.Beginform and unobtrusive ajax. I like this tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is misspelling id of the minicart div. Your id do not contain any capital letters but your selector does. So instead $("#miniCart") you should use $("#minicart") and it will work.

Comment: I'm so embarrassed! That was the answer, thank you very much! Well if you want easy kudo's, keep following my questions. Because I'm such a beginner at webdevelopment....

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this and check if it works

```
function categoryChosen() {
    var url = "Home/CategoryChosen?SelectedCategorieID=" + "2";
    $.post(url, function (data) {
        debugger;
        $("#miniCart").html(data);
    });
}
```

This is provided considering that you haven't did any changes to your routers in global.asax

rather you should add the url like this

[UrlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for answering. Not the answer to my question though. I already tried to explain that I didn't try to pass 2 along in the url, but rather in the controller itself. Sorry for the confusion.